# NW.js chrome.gcm. API doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-chrome-app, node-webkit, nwjs

I have chrome packaged app, and there I use GCM.

NW.js said that they will continue to support chrome APIs in [this article](http://nwjs.io/blog/chrome-apps-support/), but I can't get a registration ID when using `chrome.gcm.register`.

Any news about this? Is this API still supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `--enable-gcm` flag in command line.

Example(OS X):

```
open -n -a nwjs --args --enable-gcm /path/to/app/
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Transitioning from Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/migration), Chrome packaged and hosted apps will remain supported and maintained for the foreseeable future on **Chrome OS** only. It was stated further:

> Chrome packaged and hosted apps **will be discontinued on Windows, Mac, and Linux** over the course of now and early 2018. For more information, refer to the August 2016 [Chromium blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html).

For this concern, please try going through the given documentation above for the recommended migration options for packaged apps.